# I'm getting segmentation fault and valgrind shows me this error with getline

Tags: c, valgrind, getline

When I run valgrind I get this message:
    Invalid read of size 4
    at getdelim
    by getline
    by main(line y)
    Address is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) freed

```
int main() {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    read = getline(&line, &len, fp);     //this is the line that gives error on valgrind
    free(line);
    fclose(fp);

}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: To be more specific, please copy-paste the *full* Valgrind output into the question body, without modifications. As text. Then include an actual program that exhibits the problem, and not some pseudo-code. The code you currently show is missing crucial information and context.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but do you actually pass three command-line arguments to the program?

Comment: How does this even compile?

Comment: Can't compile: `error: ‘argv’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

Comment: `argv[2]` --> `argv[1]` ??

Comment: You need to check the return value of `fopen`. Opening a file can go wrong easily.

Answer (score 3):

The only potential error in your code involving getline is that the fopen fail, then fp is NULL, and you give it to getline.

Check the return value of fopen function and use perror or another similar function to know what's going on in case of failure.

but I'd like to point out that you're using argv and argv is not defined at all in your code (where it come from ?), and you doesn't check that argv[2] exist (argc must be greater than 2), so these point are also potential failure.

Answer (score 0):

Use main like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }

FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0], "r"); // This is a command line argument type of code.

xyz@abc:~$ ./a.out filename
```